# Removing cell values from a rasterBrick along the z-axis based on another rasterLayer

Tags: r, raster

I have a rasterbrick comprised of 12 layers, each layer representing the average temperature of a given month (layer 1 = January, layer 2 = February, etc.). All I want to do is to calculate some simple statistics such as mean and standard deviation on this brick. Here is the catch: I only want to calculate these statistics for the months corresponding to the duration of a wheat-cropping season, and remove all other cell values (i.e. change them to NAs). I have a wheat planting date rasterLayer and a wheat harvest date rasterLayer (cell values of these two rasterLayers again represent the month of the year that the wheat is planted and harvested, respectively).

I have succeeded in achieving this with the code below, but only when the wheat is planted earlier than it is harvested (i.e. the crop does not span across two years, e.g. – planted in November (11) of 2015 and harvested in April (4) of 2016).

Planting RasterLayer 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5i8kdfxl2hzulc/WPlantingCropped.gri?dl=0

Harvest RasterLayer
https://www.dropbox.com/s/idqys2djbgjv4yr/WHarvestCropped.gri?dl=0

Minimum Temperature RasterBrick
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pf5oe5rjcaqdqt/TminCropped.gri?dl=0

```
  Harvest<-raster("WHarvestCropped")
  Planting<-raster("WPlantingCropped")
  TminCropped<-raster("TminCropped)

#Split dataset into two: Separate those cells in which wheat is planted earlier than 
#its harvest date from those in which wheat is planted later than its harvest date 

  Separate<-overlay(Planting,Harvest, fun=function (x,y) {return(x-y)},filename="Separate")

  Earlier<-function(x){
    ifelse(x<0,1,
           ifelse(x>=0,NA,NA))}

  EarlierPH<-calc(Separate,Earlier, filename="EarlierPH")

#Make Planting dataset consisting of only those cells in which wheat is planted earlier than harvest      

  EarlierPlant<-overlay(EarlierPH,Planting,fun=function (x,y) {return(x*y)}, 
                       filename="EarlierPlant",overwrite=T,na.rm=T)

#Make Harvest dataset consisting of only those cells in which wheat is planted later than harvest  

  EarlierHarvest<-overlay(EarlierPH,Harvest, fun=function (x,y){return(x*y)}, 
                        filename="EarlierHarvest",overwrite=T,na.rm=T)


#Expand planting and harvest rasterLayers into RasterBricks

  Expand <- function(p) {
   x <- matrix(0, nrow=length(p), ncol=12)
   x[cbind(1:nrow(x), p)] <- 1
   x <- t(apply(x, 1, cumsum))
   x[x==0] <- 0
   x
  }

  EarlyPlantingBrick<-calc(EarlierPlant,Expand,filename="EarlyPlantingBrick",overwrite=T)
  EarlyHarvestBrick <- calc(EarlierHarvest, Expand, filename="EarlyHarvestBrick",overwrite=T)

  EarlyPHJoin<-overlay(EarlyPlantingBrick,EarlyHarvestBrick, 
                      fun=function(x,y){return(x+y)}, filename="EarlyPHJoin",overwrite=T)

#Final cropping calendar template

  i <- function(f) {
    x<-f
    x[x==2]<-0
    return(x)
  }

  EarlyBrickTemplate<-calc(EarlyPHJoin, i, filename="EarlyBrickTemplate",overwrite=T)

#Final Cropping Calendar for cells in which wheat was planted earlier than harvest

  EarlyBrick <-overlay(EarlyBrickTemplate,TminCropped, 
                      fun=function(x,y){return(x*y)}, filename="EarlyBrick”,overwrite=T)
```

Again, the above code works for cells in which the wheat planting date is BEFORE the harvest date (i.e. the wheat is planted and harvested within a year), but not when the wheat planting date is in an earlier month than its harvest date (e.g. planted November 2015 and harvested April 2016). How might I do this?

Comment: `months.to.av = ifelse (harvest > plant, plant:harvest, c (1:harvest, plant:12)`

Comment: @dww This returned an error:     `Error in test[ok] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(test) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'`

Comment: This was just to show you how to calculate a list of the brick layers to use in your average for each cell. You will still need to wrap this in an `apply` to do this to each raster cell and to `extract` the brick layers that this expression lists. Consider this a pointer or suggestion, not a full answer (hence posting as a comment). N.b i think you will have to extract brick layers by name not number.